# Should we allow code touch up for syntaxic sugar

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting

I know the rules of editing :

- Do not touch the code
- **Really, Do not touch the code!**

But how should I treat an edit for syntactic sugar ?

Like changing :

```
if(true)
  i.DoSomething();
```

To :

```
if(true)
{ 
  i.DoSomething();
}
```

(Or the other way around)

Is this a valid edit? Or is the rule that asks us not to touch the code apply to this kind of formatting too ?

Comment: [This is the subject of my question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20506080/1063093) I think it got rolled back by now.

Comment: As much as I hate K&R-style bracket positioning, I hate completely superfluous brackets even more. Why would you make code take up *twice as much* precious vertical real estate?

Comment: Those “rules” are wrong. It's usually wrong to edit code **in questions**. There's nothing worse about editing code in answers than editing non-code parts of answers.

Comment: In my defense as the one who made the edit, the edit originated in the fact that the code was _poorly_ misaligned/formatted. Typically, if I don't see that someone cared enough to format for the sake of future visitors, I'll go in and reformat it with a consistent style that showcases readability. As long as it doesn't cause the code block to scroll, vertical real estate does not matter. You are scrolling anyway to view answers. The point is, don't just copy/paste code without formatting. It doesn't take that long. Look at my questions and answers on SO and tell me my formatting is horrible.

Comment: @Scott Then you can ask the user to do so in the comment section. You shouldn't touche the code at all. Even if it is poorly formatted. A limit **has** to be set and the code part is simply off limit. You could simply tell the user to change the formatting or recommend that he does. Also the way you format your own question isn't relevant.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd - That would require more work for them and they may never come back. It's just as easy for me to go in and quickly align things for future visitors. That's one of the major points of editing is to clean things up. That's what I do. If I'm not affecting the code, which I didn't, what do you care?

Comment: @Scott Aligning code is one thing. Adding code parts like brackets is another. You cannot modify the code. I care because I care about established rules on this website and I'm trying to find out what is so hard to understand in *please do not touch the code*.

Comment: @Scott Alright. Just don't be surprised if your edits keep getting rollback like yesterday.

Comment: You're the first to do so in 3 years. If you want to follow me around, that's up to you.

Comment: @Scott This discussion is leading nowhere since it seems you don't care about the rules. Btw I wasn't the one to rollback the edit yesterday.

Comment: Of course I care about the rules.  What I don't care for is someone making a big deal over something so small.  I care about readability more than I do coding style.  If the underlying code ***does not change*** and the edit makes the answer or question more readable for future visitors, that to me, is a valid edit.

Answer (score 4):

Syntactic sugar usage is, at its heart, a stylistic choice, and [you should not be making such edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200172/style-changes-in-edits). Changing the syntax might add or remove minor errors as well.

However, such sugar can make code more readable, which is important to making a question easier to answer. A comment about it would certainly be appropriate, and [adding whitespace to code is OK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131105/191706) (assuming the language isn't whitespace dependent).

As for changing brackets per your example, [don't do it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133226/191706).

Answer (score 3):

You really do not know if the lack of "sugar" is the cause of some error.

For example if someone in js wanted to do two things after an if statement and showed his code like so:

```
if(true)
  i.DoSomething();
i.DoSomethingElse();
```

There is an error there and if I edit it to this:

```
if(true) {
  i.DoSomething();
}
i.DoSomethingElse();
```

I basically destroy what the OP tried and lose his error in the process.

---

The answer to the question is that the OP *should*  have done:

```
if(true) {
  i.DoSomething();
  i.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

(in case you were wondering)